# Loop through DeserializeObject Session in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, session

I am trying to loop through DeserializeObject Session object  and I am having the error

*CustomerBasket' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'CustomerBasket' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Customer Basket class

```cs
public class CustomerBasket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Prix Unit")]
    public string ItemPriceCfa { get; set; }
    public string DiscountItemPriceCfa { get; set; }
    public int? Quantity { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Prix Total")]
    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Add Item to Class

```cs
var orderdetailstEntry = new List<CustomerBasket> 
{
   new CustomerBasket {Id = itemId, Quantity=qty, TotalPrice= itemvalue.ToString(),
   Reference=basket.Reference,Description=basket.Description, I 
   temPriceCfa=basket.ItemSalePrice},
};
```

Passing  List to a session

```cs
HttpContext.Session.SetString("ShoppingCard", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderdetailstEntry));
```

I am having the error here when trying to loop through  DeserializeObject Session object  I think I am missing something I need to transform the session into a list but don't know how to do it

```cs
var getShoppingCard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerBasket>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("ShoppingCard")) ;

foreach (var memorycount in getShoppingCard.ToList())
{
   getShoppingCard.Where(w => w.Id == memorycount.Id).ToList().ForEach(s => s.OrderId = orderId);

   totalorder = totalorder + Convert.ToInt32(memorycount.TotalPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deserializing your object to `CustomerBasket` instead of `List<CustomerBasket>` thats why the `ToList` extension is not available.

```cs
var getShoppingCard = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomerBasket>>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("ShoppingCard"));
```